# Is 37Signals Basecamp a hype?

Tags: project-management

What's so unique about it? Heard great things about it, used it, found that beside the Google Apps Integration there's nothing really special about it. Maybe I just don't get it?

So, what's your reason to use basecamp?

Comment: PM.se has some great resources related to this: http://pm.stackexchange.com/search?q=basecamp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To me, the biggest draw has been the simplicity, which leads to flexibility. The concepts that Basecamp helps to manage are easily understandable, and there's very little configuration to worry about. (Have you ever tried to use a tool like JIRA? Even its configuration has configuration.)

The simplicity starts to pay dividends when you are composing project teams of varying technical experience. The basic nature of to-do list items and milestones are easily understandable by most anybody.

Answer (score 3):

It's a great way to centralize information on projects and to have a solid record of communication between users. It's also great if you are working with a distributed team.

Answer (score 2):

I've used it a few times to organise groups for various aims and I would do so again. It's easy to use, easy to understand and it does stuff you need but not stuff you don't need. I just found it really easy to get along with.

Answer (score 2):

Basecamp is great for simple project managing. If you are running a company that just needs all the team members to see what is happening and stay on the same page, then it is great. I have also found that it works wonders for design teams. Todo lists, claender events, and facebook-like posts with comments, is what makes this easy and simple to pick up.

Many other project management tools are designed around software development. They have issues, tickets, bug reports, SCRUM sctructure or whatever. This makes sense to software devs, but designers and average businessmen just don't think that way. This is why basecamp is so popular. It was really created for those.

Basecamp does NOT work for software teams. Trust me, we have tried many times. If you are developing a software, then you need something like unfuddle, assembla, or Jira.

The real problem is that programmers do not work in a funnel. They need to deal with technical writers, designers, and project leads, and for this basecamp's tools are better. I am waiting for someone to come out with a tool that offers the best of both sides. Out of the thousands of project managers, they are all either on one side or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything wrong with it, but there are a lot of other ways to address the same issues.  I also do not understand the love/loyalty it seems to generate with some users.

Personally, it has never fit what I was working on very well, so I have never had a place to use it long-term.